# Filling gap in concrete porch

Tags: concrete, hole, porch

My house has a concrete front porch with a gap underneath the slab. It's unsightly, but hasn't previously caused any issues. Unfortunately, a family of skunks recently discovered it and decided to nest there. They've moved on, but I want to avoid other guests if possible.

What is the best way to deal with this issue that doesn't involve completely re-doing the porch?

[image: hole in porch near front walkway]

Comment: It looks like man made drainage

Comment: @Ruskes so sealing this up would be a bad idea? Or do you think it's something left over from a previous project in the past that I can ignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no indication that there was any drainage there.

Cementing with wire is a good idea however you need to do it all around the slab where it is on soil.

I had to do this to a slab for my shed. If I filled one place in a few weeks,  (sometimes days!) the critters would dig under again.

If you dig just about 8 to 12 inches down at the face of the slab and slightly under the edge. Only about an inch, making a pocket or skirt of concrete and wire around the perimeter, it will prevent pests from getting under your slab. [image: My poor artistic interpretation] Then if something tries to dig under the slab it will find it difficult and go someplace else. Even after a few years when the concrete cracked, the stuff was such a pain to the small animals trying to under my shed that they would go be a nuisance to the neighbors.

Answer (score 1):

$4 of mortar mix from the hardware store + a piece of chicken wire. Lay the chicken wire against the hole, then bend it perpendicular to the slab, flat with the soil. Make sure it's at least 1' on the soil, to avoid the animals from digging underneath. Mix mortar, apply. Have beer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like man made drainage (on purpose). Clearly a drain construction, with the tunnel.

Just block it with some mesh wire to stop unwanted moving in.

This way it will still serve as drainage.

[image: drain]

Comment: This does not look like drainage to me.  #1, the inside is lower than the outside—that means if it's drainage, the ultimate outfall is somewhere beyond the edge of the slab. #2 there's a gutter downspout going *away* from the slab a fair piece.  If that hole was drainage, the downspout wouldn't need to go so far away, it would just daylight near the hole.

Comment: @Huesmann Skunks  do not dig square hole

Comment: Your idea of square must differ vastly from mine.  The only thing "square" about that IMO is the side of the stem wall.